# Norm of the linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Could you help me, please with the following question?
There is a linear functional $A : C_{[0;1]} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that

$$  Ax=\int_{a}^{b}x(t)\varphi(t)dt  $$

where $\varphi$ is a fixed fucntion, $\varphi \in C_{[0;1]}$.
The task is to prove that $ \left \| A \right \| = \int_{a}^{b}\left | \varphi (t) \right |dt $.

The norm in $C_{[0;1]}$ is $||x||=\max_{a \leq t \leq b} |x(t)|$.

———
Here is what I did.

First of all we show that the functional is bounded

$\forall x \in C_{[a;b]} ~~~ | Ax | = |\int_{a}^{b}x(t)\varphi(t)dt| \leq \int_{a}^{b} | x(t)| \cdot |\varphi(t)|dt \leq \int_{a}^{b} \max_{a \leq t \leq b} |x(t)| \cdot |\varphi(t)|dt = ||x||\cdot \int_{a}^{b}\left | \varphi (t) \right |dt $

Now i need to prove the inverse inequality or find the sequence of continuous functions with the limit function $x_0$ satisfying $A(x_0)=\int_{a}^{b}\left | \varphi (t) \right |dt~~$?

Or, perhaps, there is some other way? How can i prove that $~~\int_{a}^{b}\left | \varphi (t) \right |dt ~~$ is really a norm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean linear operator.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal From what I read $Ax$ is a number, not a function. This is a linear functional.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the misprint. I mean exactly functional.

Comment: @julien: The OP just edited the post. Now, it is a linear functional.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal From the edit record, it has a always been a functional. The typo was in the codomain. But hey, who cares, now that everybody agrees it is a linear functional.

Comment: @julien: Anyways, it is for his benefit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So you've proven that $\|A\|\leq \|\phi\|_1=\int_a^b|\phi(t)|dt$.

To get the reverse inequality, you have the right idea. You can construct a sequence of continuous functions which approximate the sign function of $\phi$. Note the limit will not be continuous as soon as $\phi$ does not have constant sign. Here is one way to do that.

I assume from now on that $\phi\neq 0$, i.e. $\|\phi\|_\infty>0$, for otherwise everything is trivial. Now set
$$
x_n(t):=\frac{\phi(t)}{|\phi(t)|+\frac{1}{n}}.
$$
This is clearly continuous and, since $y\longmapsto y/(y+1/n)$ is increasing for $y\geq 0$, we have
$$
\|x_n\|_\infty=\frac{\|\phi\|_\infty}{\|\phi\|_\infty+\frac{1}{n}}\longrightarrow 1.
$$
On the other hand, we get
$$
Ax_n=\int_a^b\frac{\phi(t)^2}{|\phi(t)|+\frac{1}{n}}dt\longrightarrow \int_a^b|\phi(t)|dt
$$
since
$$
\left|Ax_n-\int_a^b|\phi(t)|dt\right|=\left|\int_a^b \frac{-\phi(t)}{n|\phi(t)|+1}dt\right|\leq \int_a^b \frac{|\phi(t)|}{n|\phi(t)|+1}dt\leq \frac{b-a}{n}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\|A\|\geq \frac{Ax_n}{\|x_n\|_\infty}\longrightarrow \int_a^b|\phi(t)|dt.
$$
This proves the reverse inequality. Hence $\|A\|= \|\phi\|_1=\int_a^b|\phi(t)|dt$.

Comment: @Igor You'r welcome! Note that $\int_a^b|\phi|$ is a norm. It is called the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: Interesting thing. I found this task in the Russian edition of "Introductory Real Analysis" by Kolmogorov and Fomin. And it is given in the book before the chapter where measure theory is introduced. 

I really like your solution but i'm interested: could the task be done without Lebesgue's theorem?

Comment: @Igor Ok, here is a DCT free proof.

Comment: I like your explicit construction. Alternatively though, if the OP has some experience with measure theory, one can simply use the fact that every measurable function is an a.e. p.w. limit of continuous functions $\phi_{n}$. Since the sign function of $\phi$ is measurable, the result follows from dominated convergence: $$||A||\geq\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}\phi_{n}\phi\;dx=\int_{a}^{b}|\phi(x)\|;dx=||\phi||_{1}.$$ This technique comes up in a lot of situations involving integral operators and uniform boundedness principle; the most famous is Fourier series and the Dirichlet kernel.

Comment: Estimating $||A||$ by the triangle inequality (as the OP did) also shows $||A||\leq||\phi||_{1}$, so in fact $||A||=||\phi||_{1}$. This applies to convolutions as well, a common class of integral operators, so is helpful fact to keep in mind, since information about $A$ can be obtained from information about its kernel $\phi$.

Comment: @JTian The trivial part is $\|A\|\leq\|\phi\|_1$...and it has already been proven by the OP. What we need is the reverse inequality... And finally, I don't think what the OP used is called the triangular inequality.

Comment: @julien I'm ashamed. The task turned out to be so easy. Thank you very much again!!!

Comment: @Julien, see my previous comment about the harder direction. And I often see the estimate $\int f\leq\int|f|$ termed "triangle inequality," which is exactly what the OP used to obtain the easy estimate.

Comment: @JTian Agreed, not a bad thing to view this as a triangular inequality. Now, again, $\|A  \|\leq...$ was already obtained. It remains to prove $\|A\|\geq ...$. And for this, there is more work to do...

Comment: @JTian I see. You meant the comment before your previous comment. To apply DCT, you need an integrable upper bound for the integrands independent of $n$, as you know. If you simply say that the sign function is an a.e. pointwise limit of continuous functions, you don't get this requirement without further work and you can't apply DCT. There is no such problem when you use the explicit sequence I used. Anyway, the OP explicitly asked me not to use Lebesgue DCT.