# To find the norm of a linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $y\in C[a,b]$ and $f(x)=\int\limits_a^bx(t)y(t)dt$ for all $x\in C[a,b]$. I want to show that $f$ is bounded and $\|f\|=\int\limits_a^b|y(t)|dt$.

I tried the problem as follows:

$|f(x)|=|\int\limits_a^bx(t)y(t)dt|\leq\int\limits^a_b|y(t)|dt\|x\|_{\infty}$.

Thus $f$ is bounded and $\|f\|\leq\int\limits_a^b|y(t)|dt $. Now the problem is how to choose a function $z\in C[a,b]$ such that $|f(z)|=\int\limits^a_b|y(t)|dt  $? Please help!

Comment: Maybe in your last line you mean  $f(z) $ istead of  $z(t)$  ?

Comment: And Possiibly duplicate  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338758/norm-of-the-linear-functional

Comment: @Nizar Yes, I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a series of functions $s_n$ to be $$s_n(x)= \begin{cases} \mathrm{sign}(g(x)) &\mbox{if } |g(x)|\geq n^{-1} \\
\text{linear} & \mbox{O.W.} \end{cases} $$
Meaning it takes the sign of $g(x)$ whenever $g(x)$ is far enough from $0$. To make sure it is continous we define it be linear (connecting the different signs).

Obviously if $g \equiv 0$ then there is nothing to prove (as the claim is obvious). Otherwise $\| s_n \| _\infty =1 $

We also note that $\forall \varepsilon > 0 . \exists N$ such that $\forall n \geq N$ We have $$\int_a^b |g(x)| -\varepsilon \leq \int_a^b g(x) \cdot s_n(x) dx  \leq \int_a^b |g(x)|$$

Then obviously $|f(s_n)| \leq \|f\|_\text{op}$ but $|f(s_n)| \rightarrow \int_a^b |g(x)|dx$.

Together with the inequality you showed - we realize it must be an equality.